# I am converting a python/kivy project to apk in google colab and some extension are not working so what extension I should use for audio/font file?

Tags: python, android, kivy, google-colaboratory, extension-methods

I use jpg file for image but when I run my app in phone it won't open but it works for PNG file.
And also for audio file I use mp3, OGG file my app won't open but when I use wav file my app works but the sound doesn't come.
And for font file, both TTF and OTF extension won't work i.e. my app won't work

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem a bit, now the wav file is working correctly because I add the extension of wav file in the google colab file which  created after the compilation of my files (Buildozer.spec) but the problem with jpg is still there and for mp3 also

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).